# Shell variable in <a href> tag

Tags: bash, shell, variable

I wrote a simple bash script, those send mail with html link.

```
#!/bin/bash
ASS=10
sendmail kenny@gmail.com <<EOF
Subject: Simple title
<html>
<body>
this is just a link
URL: <a href="http://test.site/index?redirect=tail_$ASS_Tail\$1&noAUTO=1">Go to site</a>
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

But when email arrived, $ASS not insert in link and i see the following
http://test.site/index=tail_$1&noAUTO=1
How fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `_` is a valid variable constituent character. You have:

```
URL: <a href="http://test.site/index?redirect=tail_$ASS_Tail\$1&noAUTO=1">
```

Here the variable name is being taken as `ASS_Tail` i.e. upto the maximum number of valid characters (upto `\`) starting from `ASS`.

You need to enclose the variable name declaration with `${}` when there are valid characters following the name:

```
URL: <a href="http://test.site/index?redirect=tail_${ASS}_Tail\$1&noAUTO=1">
```